# The procedure entry point DecodePointer could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

Tags: windows, dll, windows-2000

I had this error when opening notepad and sometimes other software until I reinstalled Windows 2000 yesterday. It's come back after I copied a profile over. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DecodePointer is a function which comes with Windows XP SP2 and is not supported on Windows 2000 (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432242%28VS.85%29.aspx)). So my guess is that you installed software which is not suited for Windows 2000 and which perhaps overwrote some DLLs with newer improper versions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. So it would appear that kernel32.dll is being changed somehow as notepad is supposed to be standard. I've installed Avast and TortoiseSVN so I suspect this is coming from another source. A virus scan found a rogue dll in the temp folder but nothing conclusive yet.

Comment: Upon close investigation, the original dll from another install is 732.432 bytes and the modified date is tuesday 7 december 1999, 14:00:00. The other kernel32.dll is in all uppercase and is 712.464 bytes and modified date is tuesday 16 august 2005, 02:39:00. Hoping that the system file checker is properly disable, I'm going to see if reinstalling a service pack will solve the issue.